# IPアドレスで、CIDRのサブネットが重複することがどういうことなのかよくわかりません

Tags: ipアドレス

### 疑問点

IPアドレスの問題で、CIDRのサブネットが重複することがどういうことなのかよくわかりません。

### 疑問内容

ある問題で、
『2つのアプリケーションを各サブネット（192.168.1.0/27、192.168.1.16/27）に移動させる』という選択肢がありました。
この選択肢は不正解で、理由が
『/27はCIDRのサブネットが重複するため間違い（/28は正解）』
という内容でした。
この『CIDRのサブネットが重複するため間違い』の意味がよくわかりません。

### 考えたこと 1

サブネットのIPアドレスを２進数にすると（同じ内容は省略しています）
192.168.1.0/27→ - . - .00000001.00000000
192.168.1.16/27→ - . - . 00000001.00010000
で、
両者とも使用できるIPアドレス数は32個。
なので各IPアドレスが使用できるIPアドレス範囲は
192.168.1.0/27 → 192.168.1.0〜192.168.1.31
192.168.1.16/27 → 192.168.1.16〜192.168.1.47
となり一部IPアドレス（192.168.1.16〜192.168.1.31）が被っている

この『一部IPアドレスが被っている』＝『CIDRのサブネットが重複するため間違い』
という解釈をしましたが腑に落ちません。

### 考えたこと 2

サブネットのIPアドレスを２真数にすると（同じ内容は省略しています）
192.168.1.0/27→ - . - .00000001.00000000
192.168.1.16/27→ - . - . 00000001.00010000
その内サブネット部が
192.168.1.0/27→ - . - .00000001.**000**00000
192.168.1.16/27→ - . - . 00000001.**000**10000
となり、これが同じ数値だから被っている

これが『CIDRのサブネットが重複するため間違い』ということになるのでしょうか？

### お願いしたいこと

そもそもの解釈間違いやわかりやすい説明動画などあればご指摘、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 192.168.1.16は 00000001.00010000ではないでしょうか

Comment: すいません、凡ミスでした…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 192.168.1.0/27 → 192.168.1.0〜192.168.1.31
> 192.168.1.16/27 → 192.168.1.16〜192.168.1.47

これは間違いです。
192.168.1.16/27 が含まれるネットワークアドレスは 192.168.1.16 から 32 個ではなく、同じネットワークアドレス 192.168.1.0/27 です。

プレフィックス "/27" でサブネットで分ける場合、以下の区切りとなり、途中で区切ることはできません。
ネットマスク 255.255.255.224 で考えた方がわかるかもしれません。

```
192.168.0.0/27    (192.168.1.0   - 192.168.1.31)
192.168.0.32/27   (192.168.1.32  - 192.168.1.63)
192.168.0.64/27   (192.168.1.64  - 192.168.1.95)
192.168.0.96/27   (192.168.1.96  - 192.168.1.127)
    :
192.168.0.224/27  (192.168.1.224 - 192.168.1.255)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。/27の場合、ネットワークアドレスから32個ずつ区切られている、ということですね！その区切られた同じ範囲内にあるIPアドレスを各サブネットに指定しそこにアプリケーションを配置しても、同じネットワーク内にいるから実質分けたことにならない、ということでしょうか？

Comment: 「ある問題」がわかりませんが、「同じネットワーク内にいるから実質分けたことにならない」ということだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！